# Maximum call stack size exceeded crash - Firebase on child added listener

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been getting the maximum call stack size exceeded crash when starting my node js server (using the firebase-admin package) if I have 1255 or more children at a reference that I'm listening to using 'on child added'.

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

If I don't add `limitToLast(1255)` to my child added listener (or anything less than 1255), the crash keeps occurring.

I want to listen to **all** previous values that exist or are added regardless of magnitude without the program crashing, but I'm not sure how to do this.

on('value') works perfectly with >10k nodes in the database reference, but not 'on child added' when initially looking up all the values.

Same issue with 'on child removed'.

Here is my 'child added' code:

```
messageRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

        var payload = {};

        var msgKey = snapshot.key;
        var msgName = snapshot.child('name').val();
        var msgContent = snapshot.child('msg').val();
        var msgTime = snapshot.child('time').val();

        var message = {msg: msgContent, name: msgName, time: msgTime};

        payload['messages/' + msgKey] = message;

        ref.update(payload);

    });
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Can you share your `on('child_added')` code?

Comment: I've added it, thanks :)

Comment: Not sure why you're getting the error, but one thing I notice is you're calling `snapshot.child` when you could call `snapshot.val().name` and avoid making another call to Firebase's database (unless Firebase is optimizing this). So I would try replacing your 3 `snapshot.child` calls with `snapshot.val().name` (and msg and time). Do you still get the problem when removing `ref.update(payload)`?

Comment: changing to snapshot.val().X didn't help, but removing ref.update(payload) stopped it from happening... so maybe it's something to do with too many concurrent update requests? but i had read that if there are too many they just go into queue... strange.

Comment: What could be happening is you are asking when a child is added. Firebase returns the first child that was added and then, using `ref.update(payload)`, you add ***another*** child. And the recursive process continues indefinitely until you hit a stack size max.

How are `messageRef` and `ref` defined?

Comment: yeah that seems like a really plausible answer but messageRef points to a different reference than the payload. var messageRef = ref.child('msgQueue'); and var ref = admin.database().ref();. basically the user sends the message to ref.child('msgQueue'), my server picks it up, sanitizes it and delivers it to ref.child('messages').child(<message key>). also weirdly the problem only occurs when i have 1255+ messages already in queue. if i put 1000 messages in the queue, it works fine.

Comment: Do you have any other listeners to the `messages` node that could be triggered from the `ref.update(payload)` call?

Comment: Are you updating the `messages/<msgKey>` node? If not, might as well `set` it instead. Not sure if this will help, but I'd be curious if this had an effect. Replace your last 3 statements with: `firebase.database().ref(\`/messages/${msgKey}\`).set({name, msg, time})`. You can rename your `msgName`, `msgContent`, and `msgTime` variables to `name`, `content`, and `time` to simplify the `set` object.

Comment: no other listeners at all, just this child added one. i will try that now, thanks :)

Comment: yeah, set works... i'm extremely confused now. thank you very much for the solution though. if you want to post it as a solution i will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`set`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) is a simpler operation that might avoid some limitations. Also I'd prefix the path passed to `ref` with `/` to ensure referencing from the root node.

Replace your last 6 statements with:

```
const message = snapshot.val();
const name = message.name;
const content = message.content;
const time = message.time;

firebase.database().ref(`/messages/${msgKey}`).set({name, msg, time})
```